# Azure search indexer is failing frequently

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I have set of files stored in Azure blob storage. I am trying to index all these files based on daily basis. Some times indexer runs are failing with errors. I am not sure why it is failing sometimes and sometimes it will run successfully.

Tried to resolve error but not able to solve it. Because sometimes indexer runs successfully and sometimes not.

Comment: please provide error details

Comment: Error: Could not read content from document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at error, it seems like some of the files in your storage are not supported for azure search indexing or files may be corrupted. Suggesting to check files are corrupted, or the files are not supported for indexing as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#supported-document-formats).

I have tried from my side and below are steps i followed,

1. I have list of files in storage account which are having different formats.

[image]

2. Created index, data source , skillset and indexer.
3. As there are different formats in data source configured allowed formats in indexer as shown below,
   [image]
4. In this case, indexer will not fail for unsupported formats.
5. Also if you don't want to stop run of indexer in failure case, you can configure setting in indexer as shown below and reference is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-common-errors-warnings),

[image]